# Google Script - setValue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to learn Google Script.  I want to write a script that uses a For Loop to save the value of each cell, clear the cell, then paste that saved value back into it.  The data is in cells C6 - C17. So far, I am able to get my For Loop to work clearing each cell one by one with a 1sec pause in between but I cant figure out how to use setValue to copy the value back into the cell.  If I change the last line to source.setValue("test") then my script works, clearing each cell then replacing it with "test".

Here is my code:

```
function forceRefresh() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Fidelity Daily");
    for (var i =6 ; i<=17;i++)
    {
        var source = sheet.getRange(i,3);
        var values = source.getValues();
        source.clear();
        Utilities.sleep(1000);
        source.setValue(values);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. In your script, `values` is `[["value"]]`. So for your script in your question, when you want to import `values` to a cell using `setValue()`, it is required to modify as follows.

#### From :

```
source.setValue(values);
```

#### To :

```
source.setValue(values[0][0]);
```

#### Note :

If you want to retrieve one value from one cell, you can use `getValue()`. In this case, `value` retrieved by `getValue()` can be used by `source.setValue(value);`.

#### References :

- [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue())
- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())
- [`setValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))

I don't know whether this is an answer for you. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  When I try source.setValue(value[0][0]) only the first letter of cell contents is copied (Cell contents are stock symbols).  When I try to test this out but using a fixed value source.setValue("test") followed by a source.setValue("test a") with a pause in between I expect to see the cells change from the stock symbol to "test" to "test a".  However, all I see is the change to "test a".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue by adding the command SpreadsheetApp.flush() after the source.clear() command.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your second question.

Utilities.sleep only runs in the beginning of each function only one time. I hope this helps.

And unfortunately there is no such command like delay(); or something, in google script.